# How to run a project in Jetbrain's Rider IDE?

Tags: c#, ide, rider

I've started to learn c# recently and I really like the Jetbrains IDEs, so I decided to pick up Rider in it's early developement phase. Since it's a brand new environment I could barely find any information about it at all.

My problem is I simply cannot run my project, I have Mono installed and I gave it's path to the IDE but it still sais "no projects to run".

Do I need something aside Mono? Or what would you recommend me to check?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8xgC.png)

Comment: My OS is Windows 10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new project:

[image: New project]

Write your code:

[image: My file]

Press Ctrl + F5 and you should see this window:

[image: Configuration]

Now simply click on **Run**. The next time you need to build it, you won't see the configuration settings, but it will still run the project. :)

Comment: Thanks but thats the problem, I can't choose my project, it sais "no projects to run". I'll upload a screenshot.

Comment: Is your project imported from VS or it is a brand new one?

Comment: I'ts a brand new project.

Comment: What is your project type? (Class Lib or Console App or which)

Comment: [link](http://puu.sh/sQuSY/60e672be87.png). Click on the drop-down and choose Edit Configurations. Now you should see this window:
[link](http://puu.sh/sQuWj/cee52dabfa.png). In here you can edit the configuration settings. Try to switch the project and give it some time to load the existing projects.

Comment: Thank you for your help Симеон Шейтанов, Ivan Shakhov, I went to the project propiteries and there wasn't a c# language level selected, not even the "default". That was the problem.

Comment: *properties ( I can't edit the comment, now the stackoverflow needs a post :) )

Comment: That's strange. Normally every new project has nothing there. My guess was that you have created a ClassLibrary and then paste Main method in it.  Could you please try to create a new ConsoleApp once again?

Comment: It was an empty solution, in a ConsoleApp I don't have the same problem

Comment: @Mate any news on this one?

Comment: Oh, It's solved in the comments, create Console App instead of empty solution, or if the problem already happened you should go to project properties and choose your language.

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same problem and I think I figured it out (without having to recreate a project from scratch).

The list in front of  "Project:" is empty when there is no runnable project.
A "Class library" for instance is not runnable.
Just pick up one of your solution's projects (in your case there is only one), right click, then "Properties", and in front of "Output type:" (where you should see "Class library"), simply select "Console application".

Now you should see it in the window appearing when you click on "Edit configurations".

Comment: You mate, you are a savior.

Comment: Bless you, my friend.  I would never have found this.

Comment: yep, that is it.

Answer (score 5):

It's solved in the comments, create Console App instead of empty solution, or if the problem already happened you should go to project properties and choose your language.

Comment: I know this is an older post but I'm running into same thing running Rider on my Mac.  "Edit Configuration" isn't giving me a choice to change anything.  I started a new .NET MVC project.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just now, coming from a dotnet new angular generated project.

What I did to solve it was to right-click solution and then add existing project.

[image: add existing project]